# How do I displaying strings?

Tags: ruby, string, math, operators

How can I get this code to work? I can't make it `puts "+"` or `puts "]"`:

```
puts " Enter an option:"
puts "------------------"
puts "1] Learn to FOIL"
puts "2] Learn to factor"
puts "3] Practice!!!!!!!"

input = gets.chomp.gsub[" ", ""]
if input == 1 then
  puts "The FOIL method is used to put together the simplified terms of a polynomial."
  puts "To FOIL, you take the first term of the first set and multiply it by the first"
  puts "and second terms of the second set. Example:"
  puts "   _______"
  puts "  /    \  \"
  puts "[5x+2][10x+4]"
  puts " equals [50x²+20x]"
  puts " "
  puts " WAIT......"
  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ
else 
  puts "NOT READY!!!!!!!"
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an editor with a syntax highlighter, so you can tell your string isn't being closed:

```
puts "  /    \  \"
```

Your final `"` is being escaped by a `\`, meaning the string isn't being closed.  You need to escape the backslash itself, with another backslash:

```
puts "  /    \  \\"
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the backslashes. Change line 13 to

```
puts "  /    \\  \\"
```

I think that answers your question, but there's still a syntax error due to that youtube URL on line 18.

Comment: Ya I know, I was just frustrated, and me and a partner were working on this for a school project, so I left him a link in the source.. It was a Rick-Roll.

Answer (score 2):

Even simpler use single quotes: `'` instead of `"` which filter input.

Answer (score 1):

You've escaped a `"` character in `"  /    \  \"`. The backslash will print the succeeding character as a literal part of the string rather than a string delimiter. To use the backslash as a literal character you have to escape it with another backslash. You can circumvent all of this by using string literal delimeters like `%q(   /   \  \ )`.

Answer (score 0):

This will never work:

```
input = gets.chomp.gsub[" ", ""]
if input == 1 then
```

`gets` returns a string: "gets" means "get string". That's why `chomp` and `gsub` work, because they're methods of String.

You can't compare `"1"` to `1`. The first is a String value, the second is a Fixnum. Trying to do so will irritate Ruby which will respond with `false` because they aren't the same type of value.

You could say:

```
input = gets.chomp.gsub[" ", ""].to_i
```

or:

```
if input.to_i == 1 then
```

or:

```
if input == '1' then
```

And:

```
  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ
```

will generate a syntax error because it's not a method or variable.

Perhaps you want the user to open their browser to that URL, or to open the browser for the user and direct it to that URL? Either way, `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ` isn't going to do it for you.